# I need to scroll a floating(fixed) UIView in my storyboard after a specific point in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, autolayout

In my storyboard, I have a parent `UIScrollView` in which I have a `UIView` of height about *2000px*.

I have designed the whole view & placed an another `UIView` at bottom of parent scroll view so that it will be fixed in the UI. But at the specific point, I need to place that UIView(i.e.fixed) to get scrolled. Like after I scroll a `UILabel`, I want to scroll that `UIView` below that & get disappeared from the bottom.

[image: red area is my fixed UIView]

I know its hard to explain but I am stuck at it for so long.

P.S. I'm using `AutoLayout`.

Comment: you can place that view outside the scroll view

Comment: Yes, Its actually outside the scroll view that why it is floating na. I want to stop its floating after a fixed point when I scroll & it should also scroll with it.

Comment: TableView is best approach for this kind of functionality. Anyway you can change bottom view frame when you reach any point in scroll view with scrollview delegate methods

Comment: @Suhail I would suggest you set the height of that view to zero after the desired scroll which makes it feel like scrolling. You can set the height when it scrolls top

Comment: @PinkeshGjr that's helpful but can you provide a much explained answer or any link? Because I've implemented it in the story board.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is probably best to have the view outside the scroll view but connect constraints to the inner view as well. You use priorities to control those constraints.

In your case you would decrease your bottom constraint priority (to 500 for instance). And you would add a constraint like `outsideView.top <= insideView.bottom`. So connect the outside view to one of the views inside the scroll view and create the relation be smaller (or greater if the 2 items are reversed) or equal to that view point.

To create a demo of this start a new project and open Main.storyboard:

- Add a scroll view with constraints to leading, trailing, top, bottom
- Add a blank `UIView` (now called `innerView`) inside the scroll view and add leading, trailing, top, bottom constraints
- Add a height constraint to `innerView` to 2000
- Add an equal width constraint between `innerView` and your scroll view
- Set bottom constraint between `innerView` and scroll view to 100
- Set a distinct color to `innerView` to see the effect
- All other constraints should be set to 0
- Add another `UIView` on the top level (now called `outerView`)
- Pin outer view to leading, trailing and bottom. Also add a height constraint to 50
- Set a distinct color to `outerView` to see the effect.

By now you should have a scrollable scroll view and a fixed view at the bottom if you run the app.

- Now connect `outerView` with `innerView` and select "vertical spacing"
- Double click the newly created constraint and modify it:
- (If needed) Reverse first and second item so that the outer view is first item
- Change relation to "less then or equal"
- (If needed) select outerView.top
- (If needed) select innerView.bottom
- Set constant to zero
- Select `outerView` and find bottom constraint to safe area (or superview) and set its priority to 500.

Now run the app. If all is correct your fixed view will be fixed until you scroll down far enough. After 2000px is visible the fixed view will be scrolling with scroll view.

You can naturally pin it to any view in scroll view to get any possible effect you need.

I hope this is descriptive enough. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the solution but I've solved it using scroll view delegate methods.